# Check array of size n for value without looping

Tags: c#

I have a function that can take an array of custom objects like so

```
public static void myFunction(myObject[] myObject){
```

This list can contain 'n' number of objects. I would like to check each property of each object at once, without knowing the size of the array.

For example, I want to check that none of my objects has a property called 'name', with a value of 'fred', I want to do something like :

```
if(myObject[0] != "fred" || myObject[1] != "fred" || myObject[n] != "fred"){
```

Is there a simple way of doing this ? I don't want to do a for loop as if it doesn't equal 'fred' then it will throw an error.

Comment: What do you mean "without looping"? Without **any** loop or without writing the loop yourself?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the [`All`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548541(v=vs.110).aspx) function using [LINQ](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/).

```
if (myObject.All(o => o.Name != "fred"))
{
    // No Fred's found!
}
```

**Update:**
As Panagiotis Kanavos mentioned, [`Any`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534972(v=vs.110).aspx) might be a better solution as this will stop iterating when a match is found.

```
if (!myObject.Any(o => o.Name == "fred"))
{
    // No Fred's found!
}
```

Comment: All and Any does different things, they're not interchangeable, it's not just a case of optimizations.

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen I'm not so sure you are correct. `!Any(condition)` is the same as `All(!condition)` - but it is more optimized and more readable.

Answer (score 6):

Have you heard about LINQ?
Seems to me you are looking for [`Any`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534972(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
if(myObject.Any(o => o.Name == "fred"))
{
    // You have an object with the name "fred"...
}
```

If you want to check if all your objects have the name "fred", you can use `All`:

```
if(myObject.All(o => o.Name == "fred"))
{
    // all your objects have the name "fred"...
}
```

Comment: Yeah, Linq is awesome :-) though my answer was 10 seconds slower, it was correct from the first version. However you should accept Jerodev's answer, he needs that 15 points rep more then I do.

Comment: haha this is true, however, I do need to use the .All as I need to check than no objects in the array contain the string

Comment: No, you need `if(!Any(...)`.

Comment: Could you elaborate on the difference ?

Comment: Using `All()` will iterate until a false predicate is found (and return false) or the entire length of the `IEnumerable` (and return true), while using `Any()` will iterate until a true predicate (and return true) is found or the entire length of the `IEnumerable` (and return false). so `if(!myObject.Any(o => i.Name == "fred")` is basically the same as `if(myObject.All(o => i.Name =! "fred")`.

Answer (score 1):

I might be missing the point, but the size of an array is given by its `Length` property.

As for doing what you want, I don't think there's a way of doing it without iterating over it somehow.

Comment: see other answers :)

Comment: That's not wrong, though. Any and All will both iterate the IEnumerable (array in your case), you just don't need to write the loop yourself.

Answer (score 0):

you can use a while loop,

```
 Continue=true;i=0;
 while(continue and i < MyObject.length() ){ if (Myobject[i] != 'fred') continue=false else i++;}
 if (!continue) {  "throw your exception" }
```

Comment: Do you feel that this approach is more readable / maintainable / efficient than the other solutions given?

Comment: `continue` is reserved keyword to skip current iteration but still maintain the loop sequence.

Comment: the same as it's implemented in All or Any

Answer (score 0):

Use LINQ :

```
using System.Linq;

// ....
if(myObject.Any(element => (string)element == "fred"))
{
    // do what ever you need to do
}
```

Note that when you use this LINQ expression it's just a shortcut for a loop and it's equivalent to creating your own Any function like this :

```
bool Any(string keyword)
{
    foreach (var element in myObject)
    {
        if(element == keyword)
           return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: `Any` is a bit more advanced than that though, since it allows any parameter, not just string. You can check the [referencesource](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs,8788153112b7ffd0) for that.

Comment: @Default I know it's just that I wanted to simply things to make the point about the loop thing